# What's the Clojure equivalent of inject:into: in Smalltalk?

Tags: clojure, lisp, smalltalk, combinations

I'm trying to learn Clojure but my synapses seem to be hard-wired to Smalltalk.

What's the equivalent of this function?

```
[:n :k | (1 to: k) inject: 1 into: [:c :i | c * (n - k + i / i)]]
```

- this is the binomial coefficient for n, k - also known as "choose" function, representing the number of combinations of n things taken k times

Comment: Awesome. This is what I came up with (defn choose [n k] (reduce (fn [c i] (* c (/ (+ (- n k) i) i))) 1 (range 1 (+ k 1)))). It was pretty easy once I figured out how to convert the Smalltalk infix notation to Lisp but the syntax still hurts my brain :)

Comment: Instead of `(+ k 1)` you can also use `(inc k)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The clojure equivalent of `lst inject: s into: f` is `(reduce f s lst)`

Comment: Too fast, too fast. I was about 20 seconds too slow!

Comment: I would rather say that `#inject:into:` is the equivalent to `reduce` since smalltalk get inspire by lisp :)